# Saving my for loop as data frame or list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to save the results of my nested for loop in a data frame or list. (As I will get quite a lot of data in the end, it is too much just to print I found out.

I want to create an empty data.frame with 5 columns (i,j,fLat,fLon, Rainindex) and save all the output from my for loop.

This is what my code looks like with just printing it.

```
for (i in 1:380){
  for (j in 1:530){
  fLat <- lati[i,j]
  fLon <- long[i,j]
  Rainindex <- sum(pr_array[i,j,1:123])
  print(c(i,j,fLat,fLon, Rainindex))
 }}



[1]   1.0000    1.0000   54.7000   10.4500  153.6514
[1]   1.00000   2.00000  54.71746  10.44813 150.76996
[1]   1.00000   3.00000  54.73491  10.44626 143.46000
[1]   1.00000   4.00000  54.75237  10.44438 137.22394
[1]   1.00000   5.00000  54.76984  10.44250 148.15934
     etc. etc.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a NULL object and add each output using `rbind` like this:

```
New_Df = NULL
for (i in 1:380){
  for (j in 1:530){
  fLat <- lati[i,j]
  fLon <- long[i,j]
  Rainindex <- sum(pr_array[i,j,1:123])
  vec <- c(i,j,fLat,fLon, Rainindex))
  New_Df <- rbind(New_Df, vec)
 }}
New_Df <- as.data.frame(New_Df)
colnames(New_Df) <- c("i","j","fLat","fLon","Rainindex")
```